# Using square brackets with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom

PHP's DOMDocument's handling of square brackets is very frustrating. I want the document to contain `&#91;bbcode&#93;`, but I'm unable to do so:

```
$dom->createTextNode('[bbcode]'); // outputs "[bbcode]"


$dom->createTextNode('&#91;bbcode&#93;'); // outputs "[bbcode]"


$dom->createTextNode('&amp;#91;bbcode&amp;#93;'); // outputs "&amp;#91;bbcode&amp;#93;"
```

How can I make PHP output `&#91;bbcode&#93;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `createEntityReference()` method to create entities.

```
 $dom->createEntityReference('#91');
 $dom->createEntityReference('#93');
```

and then append it in correct places.

Comment: I have to replace square brackets in text nodes, so I don't think this approach is feasible: `$frag->appendXML(str_replace(array('[',']'),array('&amp;#91;','&amp;#93;'),$node->nodeValue));`

Comment: @Linksku It's recommended way to achieve it and maybe only one that exists.